# Spring scope request hashcode

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring, when the Scope of the bean is set to "request", for EACH request a new object will be generated. I want to test this but for every request I get the same hashcode value.

```
Question-

1. Should'nt the hash code value should be different since new object is generated.

Output for 4 http requests using Chrome and IE browser

emp hashcode == 172261326
emp hashcode == 172261326
emp hashcode == 172261326
emp hashcode == 172261326


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController {
    @Autowired
    private Employee emp;

    public Employee getEmp() {
        return emp;
    }

    public void setEmp(Employee emp) {
        this.emp = emp;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("emp hashcode == " + emp.hashCode());
        emp.
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";
}




@Component
@Scope(value="request")
public class Employee {
    private String fname;
    private int age;
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee that each object has a unique hash code; two different objects might have the same hash code. Don't write programs that rely on different objects always having different hash codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the proxy mode you've chosen, Spring will provide an interceptor for the `hashCode` method. This will typically delegate the invocation to the advised object. You'd think that in this case the advised object would be the actual `Employee` object, but you'd be wrong. In reality, Spring provides a `SimpleBeanTargetSource` that knows how to retrieve your scoped bean.

There's only one `SimpleBeanTargetSource` object, so you're always getting the same `hashCode`.

Comment: I have not set the proxy mode.Where can I check the proxy mode?

Comment: @user1050619 It's a member of the `@Scope` type called `proxyMode`. It defaults to `ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT`. With `request` scoped beans, you should probably set it to `TARGET_CLASS` (CGLIB) or `INTERFACES` if your type was implementing an interface (JDK proxies).

Comment: Thanks.One more question - its slight different but relevant to this example.Is Employee Object declared in HelloController is threadsafe?

Comment: Thanks. I have DAO service that's a Spring bean.Where can I instantiate, should it be within the printwelcome method.

Comment: @user I don't understand. If it's a Spring bean, then it's already been instantiated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65891/discussion-between-user1050619-and-sotirios-delimanolis).